# Error in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong in this code? it shows an Syntax error in `eval(e.text); //run the script`

```
  runScripts1: function(e) {
        if (e.nodeType != 1) return false; //if it's not an element node, return

        if (e.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'script') {
            eval(e.text); //run the script
        }
        else {
            var n = e.firstChild;
            while ( n ) {
                if ( n.nodeType == 1 ) forrester.runScripts1(n); //if it's an element node, recurse
                n = n.nextSibling;
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `e.text`? Either debug the code or show it with alert or `Console.write` and post here.

Comment: But the error is thrown only in ie7. Thanks for the reply i will do an alert and check...

Comment: You should mention this in the question, we can't guess such thing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that the syntax error is *inside* the e.text -- that the script tag you're manually evaluating itself has an error.